# Does a norm based on $a(a+b)$ exist?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let's say I have a set of pairs $(a, b)$ with real components. Is it possible to define a norm on this set that satisfies $||(a, b)|| = 0 \iff a(a+b)=0$?

Generally speaking, does a function $f(a, b)$ exist with these properties?

$$f(a,b)≥0$$
$$f(a,b)=0 \iff (a=0 ∨ a+b=0)$$
$$f(ka, kb) = kf(a, b)$$
$$f(a,b)f(c,d)=f(ac,ad+bc+bd)$$
$$f(a+c,b+d)≤f(a,b)+f(c,d)$$

The last three constraints should show how multiplication and addition on these "pairs" work.

If any such function or a family thereof exists, what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. In particular, for $a \neq 0$, we have $$f(a,-a) + f(0,a) = 0$$ since $a(a + -a) = 0(0 + a) = 0$ but $$f(a + 0, -a + a) = f(a,0) > 0$$ since $a(a + 0) = a^2 > 0$.

Thus, no function exists that satisfies your first, second, and fifth conditions simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks. Just out of curiosity, is it still impossible if the last one or two constraints are dropped?

Comment: I can't think of an immediately obvious counterexample, but am not awake enough to answer that properly.